IR transmission code not working IrSender.begin();
Im new to ESP32 and Arduino. I want to Transmit IR signals using an ESP32 Wroom32 microcontroller. My IR transmitter has 3 pins S + -. I have placed S to pin 26 + to 3.3v and - to Ground of the ESP32. My IRremote library version is 4.4.1
I'm using the following code but its not working. I can find what's wrong. Can somebody please help?
    #include <IRremote.hpp>
    #define IRPin 26         // Transmitter pin


    uint8_t sCommand = 0x34;
    uint8_t sRepeats = 0;
    void setup() {
    Serial.println(9600);
    IrSender.begin(IRPin);
    }

    void loop() {
    IrSender.sendSony(0x01, sCommand, sRepeats);
    Serial.println("IR send....");
    delay (5000);
    }


I get no output. not even Serial.print output.

Try Serial.begin(9600) insted of Serial.println(9600). Also, are you sure you have an Ir sender, not an Ir receiver. They have 3 pins. An IR sender is just an Ir led.
